# Add class to a div next to the one deleted

Tags: jquery, mongodb

I have a container class inside which there are many `<div>`s.
When I click on one div, I add a *selected* class to it.  After deleting one div, I display the contents of the next div after it.

I would like the *selected* classes to be added to it.  How can I do this?

```js
    

 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
 const remote = require('electron').remote;
 const main = remote.require('./index.js');
 var arr=[];
 var dict=[];
 var i=0;
var index=0;
var ed=0;
window.addEventListener("load", function () {

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("ChatBot");
  var cursor = dbo.collection("Chats").find();
  console.log(cursor);

  cursor.each(function(err,item){
    console.log(item);
    if(item!=null)
    {
      console.log(item.username+" "+item.request+" "+item.botRp);
      arr.push(item.username);
      dict.push({
        key:   item.username,
        user: item.request,
        bot : item.botRp
  });
     

    }
  });
});
myLoop();


}, false);

  function myLoop () {           //  create a loop function
  setTimeout(function () {
 if(ed==0)
 {
  $('#foo').append('<div class="ruser" style="margin-top:1em;">'+
      '<div class="rname z-depth-2 hoverable">'+
       '<h5>'+arr[i]+'</h5>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="test'+(i+1)+'"  />'+
        '<label for="test'+(i+1)+'" class="checkl" style="display:none"></label>'+
     '</div>');
        ed++;
  }
  else {
    $('#foo').append('<div class="ruser">'+
        '<div class="rname z-depth-2 hoverable">'+
         '<h5>'+arr[i]+'</h5>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="test'+(i+1)+'"  />'+
          '<label for="test'+(i+1)+'" class="checkl" style="display:none"></label>'+
       '</div>');

  }
  if((i+1)==1)
  {
      $('#disp').html('You have '+(i+1)+" new message");
  }
  else{
    $('#disp').html('You have '+(i+1)+" new messages");
  }

  i++;                   //  increment the counter
  if (i < arr.length) {            //  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
     myLoop();             //  ..  again which will trigger another
  }                        //  ..  setTimeout()
   }, 1200);
}
 $(document).on('click', '.rname', function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  $('.rname').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
 $('.NoView').fadeOut();
 $('#chat').empty();
 var name = $(this).closest('div').eq(0).find("h5").text();
 var userRequest="";
 var botRep ="";
 for(var j=0;j<dict.length;j++)
 {
  if(dict[j].key==name)
  {
    console.log("found");
    userRequest=dict[j].user;
    botRep=dict[j].bot;
    index=j;
    break;
  }
 }
          $('#chat').append('<div class="BotWrapper">' +
            '<div class = "speech-bubble z-depth-5"><p>' + userRequest + '</p></div><div class=""></div>');
            $('#chat').append('<div class="BotWrapper">' +
                '<div class = "speech-bubble z-depth-5"><p>' + botRep + '</p></div><div class=""></div>');


  $('.medium').fadeIn();
  $('.small').fadeIn();
 });
$('#del').click(function() {
   console.log('delete');
   $(".check:checked").each(function() {
    var k=0;
    var name = $(this).closest('div').eq(0).find("h5").text();
    console.log(name+" hkhbhjjkh");
    for(var i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) {
      console.log(dict[i].key+" "+name);
       if(dict[i].key == name) {
        k=i;
        console.log('hg');
        dict.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
 }
 console.log(dict);
if(index==k)
{
  $('#chat').empty();
  $('#chat').append('<div class="BotWrapper">' +
      '<div class = "speech-bubble z-depth-5"><p>' + dict[k].user + '</p></div><div class=""></div>');
      $('#chat').append('<div class="BotWrapper">' +
          '<div class = "speech-bubble z-depth-5"><p>' + dict[k].bot + '</p></div><div class=""></div>');
}
   $(this).closest('div').eq(0).fadeOut();
   $('.rname').eq(k).addClass('selected');
});

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-item large z-depth-5">
  <div class="participants z-depth-5">
    <h4>Requests</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="Users" id="foo">
    <div class="edit">
      <button>
     <i class="material-icons right" id="del">delete</i>
     </button>
      <button>
     <i class="material-icons right waves-light " id="edit">edit</i>
     </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the image.As of now DKe1kor is selected after deleting it i want the next div i.e. Oah1kor to get the css like that.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRF74.png)

Comment: I don't see any element with class `rname` !

Comment: You need to specify which `.rname` you want the class to be added to, eg `$('.rname').eq(0).addClass('selected');`   using `$(..)[0]` will return a DOM node so jquery methods won't be available.

Comment: This is a div in my html code @HamzaAbdaoui

Comment: @freedomn-m..that's not working

Comment: Why don't just add the class when you append the div ?!!

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui It is some other div for which i'm defining this delete method when i click the checkbox and also the delete button

Comment: It will help much if you post the rest of your hmtl code..

Comment: any live example would be great

Comment: @Pedram i have added an image link to demonstrate what i want

Comment: Please add the appropriate code for the sinppet to work. Like the `dict` variable, etc. What if two div remain and you delete the last one? Should the first be given the `selected` class?

Comment: @Stphane added the entire jquery code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you were trying to apply a jQuery function to a native HTMLElement:

```
$('.rname')[0].addClass(…
```

Which naturally will not work. To apply the addClass function to the first item in the jQuery collection, you need to use the `eq()` function instead of the square brackets notation:

```
$('.rname').eq(0).addClass(…
```

To actually fix your issue, you should access the next eligible element (to apply "selected" class on it) by directly using the reference to the DOM Element that has been ticked. You could do this easily right after the fade effect has completed:

```
    // …
    $(this).closest('div').fadeOut(300, function() {
      let $t = $(this);
      // Add selected class to eligible element
      // $t.next().addClass('selected').end().remove();
      // if you would like to set the previous element as selected
      // in case last item was clicked, replace the previous line with:
      $t[$t.next().length ? 'next':'prev']().addClass('selected').end().remove();
    });
```

**Here is a demo** to see the code at work.
For simplicity, this snippet assumes that some items have already been loaded into the DOM:

```js
var dict = [
    {key: '1rst item', user: 'First user', bot: 'bot 1'}
    , {key: '2nd item', user: 'Second user', bot: 'bot 2'}
    , {key: '3rd item', user: 'Third user', bot: 'bot 3'}
], index = 0;

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  var $t = $(e.target);
  if ($t.is('.ruser')) {
      // Unselect '.selected' element
      $t.parent().children('.ruser').removeClass('selected');
      // Select current element
      $t.addClass('selected');
      // Save index
      index = dict.map((el, i) => {
         return el.key == $t.find('h5').text() ? i : null
      }).filter(x=>x!==null)[0];
      $('h4').html(`Requests <small>(Index is now equal to ${index})</small>`);
  }
});

$('#del').click(function() {
  $(".check:checked").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).closest('div').eq(0).find("h5").text()
        , $chat = $('#chat')
        , k = 0
        ;
    for (var i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) {
      if (dict[i].key == name) {
        k = i;
        dict.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (index == k && dict[k]) {
      console.log('Selected item is being deleted.');
      [dict[k].user, dict[k].bot].forEach(el => {
        $chat.append(`
          <div class="BotWrapper">
              <div class="speech-bubble z-depth-5">
                  <p>${el}</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        `);
      });
    }
    $(this).closest('div').fadeOut(300, function() {
      let $ruser = $(this)
      // Determine which will be the element eligible to 'selected' class
        , $next = $ruser.next()
        , $all = $ruser.parent().find('.ruser');
      // Deleting last make first item eligible
      !$next.length && ($next = $all.eq(0));
      $ruser.remove();
      // DO NOT REPEAT YOURSELF: "selected" class handling belongs to the click event handler above.
      // Code elsewhere should not interfer with it (Making so would harden
      // debbuging application state). So we need to trigger the click event
      // so that related actions are correctly executed 
      // (Updating "index" variable for instance).
      $(document).triggerHandler({type:'click', target: $next[0]});
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.selected{color: red}

.BotWrapper, .BotWrapper * {display: inline-block}
.BotWrapper * + * {margin-left: 10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-item large z-depth-5">
    <div class="participants z-depth-5">
        <h4>Requests</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="Users" id="foo">
        <div class="edit">
            <button id="del">
                <i class="material-icons right">delete</i>
                </button>
            <button>
                <i class="material-icons right waves-light " id="edit">edit</i>
                </button>
        </div>
        
        <!--
           Let say 3 items have already been loaded
        -->
        <div class="ruser selected">
          <div class="rname z-depth-2 hoverable">
            <h5>1rst item</h5>
          </div>
          <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="test0"  />
          <label for="test0" class="checkl" style="display:none"></label>
        </div> 
        <div class="ruser">
          <div class="rname z-depth-2 hoverable">
            <h5>2nd item</h5>
          </div>
          <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="test1"  />
          <label for="test1" class="checkl" style="display:none"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="ruser">
          <div class="rname z-depth-2 hoverable">
            <h5>3rd item</h5>
          </div>
          <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="test3"  />
          <label for="test3" class="checkl" style="display:none"></label>
        </div>       
        
    </div>
</div>
<div id="chat"></div>
```

Comment: $t.next().children().addClass('selected'); this worked for me.Thank you so much.I want to go from the last element after being deleted to the first.How do i do that.

Comment: @ANISHA you're welcome. Can you rephrase "I want to go from the last element after being deleted to the first" ?

Comment: I mean after the last element is deleted which is in this opr1kor..I want to add the class selected to the first div i.e. DKE1KOR.. not the previous element

Comment: @ANISHA I have updated my answer. If there is no next element, the first item will receive the 'selected' class.